# How can I get rid of this space between body and div?

Tags: html, css

So I centered my text. But now there is a white space between `body` and the `div`. This is the HTML:

```css
.parent-aligner {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center; 
  }

  .parent-aligner .aligner {
    display: table-cell;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parent-aligner">
      <div class="aligner">
        <p class="textcontent">lorem ipsum text</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think what causes this is the `width: 100vw;`. But when I change it to `width:100%;` the text isn't centered anymore. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `body { margin:0}`

Comment: Tried that already, but it didn't work. I've been trying to get this fixed for 40 minutes, getting desperate now :D

Comment: using bootstrap i guess ?

Comment: use font-size: 0; line-height: 0;

Comment: Positive, using bootstrap for the first time

Comment: use this magic thing * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: which version, V3 or V4 ?

Comment: here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/jek9o9mc/

Comment: Cross-browser solution: `html,body { margin: 0; }`

Comment: so the issue is with bootstrap class, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Deduct the width of the scrollbar from the viewport width for smaller screen sizes...</del>

EDIT: Add `max-width` property.

(And also remove the `margin` on `body`)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent-aligner {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-aligner .aligner {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parent-aligner">
      <div class="aligner">
        <p class="textcontent">lorem ipsum text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When there is no scrollbar, you get a blank margin due to your `width: calc(100vw - 17px);`.

Comment: am pretty sure it's bootstrap ... he's using container-fluid and no one is paying attention to it as he didn't include bootstrap (and it's adding padding)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've never seen witdh: calc(); anywhere but it seems pretty handy

Comment: @AlexandreAnnic Just noticed this, I've updated answer

Comment: @sol the old and the new answer both worked, will accept this answer after the time is over :D

Comment: @sol yup i'm using that right now instead of the calc(). But both approaches worked. And my text is still centered

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.parent-aligner {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center; 
    display:table;
  }

  .parent-aligner .aligner {
    display: table-cell;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="parallax">
    <div class="parent-aligner">
      <div class="aligner">
        <p class="textcontent">lorem ipsum text</p>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```